# date picker date month name in android

Tags: android

i am using date picker in android, when i am picking date it coming like this 10-26-2010, but i want to show date in this format October 26,2010. is it possible? please any body help.

Comment: Could you show some code? Both, DatePicker and DatePickerDialog has methods to get the year, month and day of month as integer. Use them and a Java's DateFormatter to format them as you wish.

Comment: @SudiptaforAndroid hi iam also facing this issue we have any idea of this one please help me...

Comment: @NagarjunaReddy u can go through my accepted answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an new `Date` object when the values are returned and use the appropriate methods to set it to the correct date.  You can then format it with [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Aren't the setters of Date deprecated? So you should use the Calendar.getInstance().set(foo,bar) methods instead.